# Setting android TextViews and Buttons in the code

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-button

So I need to add `TextViews` andButtons`to my code **inside** the code itself like, dynamically adding them inside a`for`loop. My problem is setting the`layout_gravity` for both and getting them unique id's. Is there a way to add an id from within the code?

**UPDATE**

I need the id of the `TextViews` and `Buttons` to get into the `R.id` folder, is that even possible?

Comment: Duplicate: [Android: Add two text views programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210599/android-add-two-text-views-programmatically)

Comment: Update: If they exist in your resources folder, then they are not created dynamically; they already exist...

Comment: Based on the answers and comments, it seems like it might be beneficial to tell us exactly what you are trying to acheive here. I can't imagine why you would need to register the ID's in the R.id folder because that's typically used at design time, not runtime, so how would you know what to look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// sets button properties
    btn = new ImageButton(this);
    btn.setId(id);
    btn.setTag(Image_Name);

    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    btn.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    btn.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        // Implement Click Listener

        }
    });
```

You can any component like these.

Comment: What is the "id" field in btn.setId(id)?

Comment: how do i set the id to be in my R.id folder?

Comment: Its your choice id can be any thing integer which will be increment at loop iterate.

Comment: its not be set in R.java file.

Comment: No if you want to set any dynamic component it will not be register in R.java

Comment: Is there no way to get it in the R.id? Because i want to set onclickListeneres to Buttons that when clicked change the textfields... :(

Comment: Above code works for the buttons differently with different Ids.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to generate ids at runtime that are still considered unique with respect to the rest of R.id, sorry.  You CAN set the ID of a view to any value you like in Java code using the `setId()` method, however, here are some options for what you might consider:

1. Set the ID of your dynamic views to values like 0, 1, 2, 3 or even 100, 101, 102, 103, etc.  You may have noticed that the values generated by R.id always start with 0x7F so it would be VERY unlikely for you to pick values that would collide.
2. Use the hashcode of the view, a la `view.setId( view.hashCode() )` to generate a more unique ID.  This is what `RadioGroup` does when its children don't have an ID.
3. You CAN generate R.id values ahead of time that are not attached to views by creating a `res/values/ids.xml` ([see SDK article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id)).  These can then be added with `view.setId(R.id.xxx)` at runtime.

As far as your `layout_gravity` problem, this is probably because values prefixed with `layout_` in XML are `LayoutParams` and not properties of the actual view.  You need to add that value to a `LayoutParams` object and set those params on your new view, a la:

```
Button button;
LinearLayout layout;
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

//Option #1 to add
layout.addView(button, lp);

//Option #2 to add
button.setLayoutParams(lp);
layout.addView(button);
```

HTH